# Key of associative table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a little problem in my project : I would like display only the key of each array when I click on a element of my list. [Dump of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkwD4.png)

For example when I click in "Paupiette", I would like display 0.

I partially succeeded but when I click in a element, I see only the last key (here "1").

Here,you can see the code

```
$carts = $cartService->getCart($user);
//dump($carts); die;
 
$mykey = 0;
foreach($carts as $key => $value) {
    $mykey = $key;
}
dump($mykey);die;
```

If you have any idea, thank you a lot

Comment: You overwrite `$myKey` every iteration. That's why you only see the last one

Comment: I must create a table to save each key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple choice to display your $keys

the first one is :

```
$keys = array_keys($carts);
```

The second is :

```
foreach ($carts as $key => $value) {
    dump($key);
}
```

if you will display all keys after loop

```
$myKeys = array();
foreach($carts as $key => $value) {
    $myKeys[] = $key;
}
dump($myKeys);die;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the keys, following your coding "style":

```
foreach ($carts as $key => $value) {
    dump($key);
}
```

If you want to display the keys as comma-separated string, again following your coding "style":

```
$keys = array_keys($carts);  // Get the keys, eg, [0, 1];
$str = implode(', ', $keys);  // Convert the array to string, eg, "0, 1"
dump($str);
```